# mysql group by with multi rows from one table

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql converting multiple rows into columns in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121812/mysql-converting-multiple-rows-into-columns-in-a-single-row)

i have a mysql table like this:

```
id |  p |  c  |  v
1     p1   10    1
2     p1   20    2
3     p1   30    3
4     p2   40    1
5     p2   50    2
6     p2   60    3
```

now i need to run a sql and get result like this:

```
p  |  as_c1 | as_c2 | as_c3
p1     10       20      30
p2     40       50      60
```

i used this query but it's not enough:

```
select 
p, 
c as as_c1,
c as as_c2,
c as as_c3
from test_tbl group by p, c
```

i searched every where, is this possible? i just need some guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT` that you are trying to perform. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function.  There are two ways to do this static or dynamic.  If you know the values that you want to transform into columns, then you can use a static version but if the values are unknown then you can use a prepared statement to generate this dynamically:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when v = ''',
      v,
      ''' then c end) AS as_c',
      v
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM table1 
                    GROUP BY p');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5456/2)

The static version would be similar to this:

```
select p,
  sum(case when v=1 then c end) as_c1,
  sum(case when v=2 then c end) as_c2,
  sum(case when v=3 then c end) as_c3
from table1
group by p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5456/3)

Comment: why i get #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE when run dynamic way in localhost phpmyadmin? someone said this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270953/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-mysql but i can't understand what he did.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p,
  ( CASE WHEN v = 1 THEN c ELSE NULL END ) AS as_c1,
  ( CASE WHEN v = 2 THEN c ELSE NULL END ) AS as_c2,
  ( CASE WHEN v = 3 THEN c ELSE NULL END ) AS as_c3
FROM `test_tbl`
GROUP BY p;
```

I think that ought to do it.

Comment: thanks, but as_c2 and as_c3 are null!

Comment: @Vahid Can you put the sample data to sqlfiddle?